# iOS 8 Extension using iCloud Data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, icloud, ios-app-extension

I have an app that uses Core Data with iCloud to sync it's data across devices.

Now I want to display some of those data using a notification center widget of iOS. It is important that the notification center is up to date even without starting the app to do an iCloud update.

So I thought it would work just to use the same iCloud persistence stack for the extension.

I'm calling the creation of the stack in the `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that the extension reconnects everytime one swipe down of the Notification Center to iCloud, which would be alright but after that it requires a second opening of Notification Center to see the current data which seems strange.

Has anybody some experience in using iCloud with this? And is there a best pratice to create an managedobjectcontext which shouldn't be reloaded overtime or is this just wrong for those kinds of extensions?

Edit: Some discussions on the dev forum are about the exact same problem but however there is no real solution for it. So I' starting this bounty.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of those cases where iCloud doesn't quite work yet. Sharing an iCloud store between an app and an extension will have these problems, and many others.

Comment: So I wonder how does Apple actually solves this in it's Reminder app? This should uses CoreData and iCloud too...

Comment: Reminders uses different XPC services.

Comment: Too bad :( so this makes many Apps not suitable for the extensions :(

Comment: Don't forget to file a bug https://bug report.apple.com

Comment: Are you observing the iCloud "did import" notification on your extension?

Comment: Yes I do observe them. But it won't help because the cloud is too slow and they don't share the same fallback store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use iCloud Core Data stores with iOS8 Extensions, according to updates in this thread in devforums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1051015#1051015